# Creating separate arrays by splitting an array according to values in another list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a matrix like the following:

```
a1 = [[ '05dcc1a8cd49fbe2e7d7fb105d697e96','122624838'],      
       ['5d9573196098ce0bb80b4657e43f2d3b','122624838'],  
       ['df29c5dafbfe8c0dcb5c92a2225c8899','3388999'],  
       ['33f95122281f76e7134f9cbea3be980f','3388999'],  
       ['b013295b38799b8c537c850ff891170e','3388999'],  
       ['b8dc623f5b936f9959e648323f061b3a','3388999']]
```

I have another list which I want to split according to the second column of the matrix. The list is as follows:

```
pred = [1,1,1,1,0,0,1..]
```

I want to obtain a separate list containing values of the list pred, according to the distinct second column values in a1. The length of a1 and pred is the same. What is the best way to do this?

(For example result1 = [1,1] since a1 has the first two values in the second column the same, result2 = [1,1,0,0] due to the next four values in the second column of a1)

Comment: Please try to give a [mcve].  A clear input, expected output and current code (if any).

Comment: What do you mean by 'second value' -- every odd entry? What would then be the criteria for sorting the values into `result1` and `result2`. Also, in your example you show lists, not `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Your question is not clear. @asmita-poddar : Your `result1`, `result2` and the list `pred`, and input list `a1` can you please explain relation in more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have considered your problem and try to write the possible solution to this.

```
#let consider you have the given values of 'a1' and 'pred'
a1 = [ '05dcc1a8cd49fbe2e7d7fb105d697e96','122624838',      
       '5d9573196098ce0bb80b4657e43f2d3b','122624838',  
       'df29c5dafbfe8c0dcb5c92a2225c8899','3388999',  
       '33f95122281f76e7134f9cbea3be980f','3388999',  
       'b013295b38799b8c537c850ff891170e','3388999',  
       'b8dc623f5b936f9959e648323f061b3a','338899'
       'bjdhjndehjkkh54jht3u5355j4jj3453','338899']
pred=[1,1,1,1,0,0,1]
count=[]
flag=1
for x in range(0,len(a1)-1):
    if x%2!=0:
        if a1[x]==a1[x+2]:
            flag=flag+1
        else:
            count.append(flag)
            flag=1
count.append(flag)
print(count)  # The length and no. of partitions

# Printing the required list of values from pred
i=0
l=0
for x in count:
    print(pred[i:l+x])
    i=l+x
    l=l+x+1
```

This will work for any value of `a1` and `pred` as long as you are considering **splitting the values in `pred` according to the number of consecutive same values in `a1`** , given that the length of both lists are same.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: i would love to know the problems in my answer as i am new to the community , it will help me to improve. let me know the reason to downvote the answer